# Display custom error message in delete dialog box

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid, custom-error-handling

I am trying to display the custom error server response in the jqgrid delete dialogue box. I see the response coming from the server but jqgrid delete dialogue box is displaying the below error message.

delege dialogue box is displaying : error status:'Locked'. Error Code:403

server response: Record locked for update.